# ER diagram - Express that only 2 of 3 keys are needed for a weak set

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

Im learning about ER diagrams, and have this assignment where i have to express an education system.

So what I can't figure out, is:

I made a entity set with "students", one with "courses" and one with "projects". I made a weak entity set "exams", so the identity is determined by what student is taking which course/project exam.

I know that I will always need the information about the student in this entity set, but how can I express that ONLY ONE of the two others is required and allowed. I want it to be either a project exam, or a course exam.

A view of my problem:

[image]

Comment: `ONLY ONE of the two others` what are the 2 others?

Comment: I want it to take the student + either course or project. Course and projects are 2 different things, but both have an exam.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some research:

When the minimum number of requirements is zero, the relationship is usually called `optional` and when the minimum number is one or more, the relationship is usually called `mandatory`.

In other words it has a mandatory foreign key attribute,

In your case it is either course or project so it is mandatory.

He're is an image that illustrate it:

[image]

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for doing the research but there seems to be no way to say: Either this OR that. Because if a course is supplied, a project is not allowed, but if no course is supplied, then project is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't the exams associated with projects and courses primarily? If so then you can have a StudentCourseExam entity, and a StudentProjectExam entity, each acting as a relation to the appropriate student, and referring to the Exams table (trinary relationship).